# migration angular 8 to 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular9

while migration from angular 8 to 9, i installed angular dependecies one by one using npm i (@angular/core, @angular/cli @angular/material ect ...)

reading the documentation using **ng update** must fix all import

[image]

i'm runing **ng update @angular/material@9**

as result i got Package '@angular/material' is already up to date.

but no imports is fixed, how can i fix all imports

Answer (score 1):

Check your package.json, if it's already with angular material 9, update won't do anything as you already are in the same version.
Rollback to angular 8 and follow the migrations steps. You're supposed to use ng update command, not npm commands. This ensures migration scripts are launched and angular handles itself its own bloat of dependences.

Note that for more recent angular versions, commands are
`ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11` and `ng update @angular/material@11`

So if simple `ng update` is not working, maybe you're supposed to launch `ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9` and `ng update @angular/material@9`